# How to solve the equation for $x$ where $x^{(x-1)^2} = 2x +1 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to solve for $x$ in the following equation
$$ x^{(x-1)^2} = 2x +1$$
Guessing $(x-1)^2=2$ is a pretty good guess and it works giving $x = \sqrt{2} +1 $

But I want a non-guess solution. I tried thinking in terms of logarithm and binomial expansion but couldn't go far.

Comment: At some point, some wag will point out that $\sqrt2+1$ *is* a real solution. Ignore them. :-) ¶ As far as I can tell, there is no elementary route to a "genuine" (i.e., non-guess?) solution. There may be something involving the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), but I'm not adept at converting equations into the proper form, and I don't see an obvious way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming $x$ is non negative, since otherwise $x^{(x-1)^2}$ might not be well defined over the reals.

If $x<1$, then $x^{(x-1)^2}<1$, but $2x+1\ge 1$, so that can't yield a solution. Now suppose $x\ge 1$.

Let $y = (x-1)^2$, so $x^y = 2x+1 =$ $x^2+2-y$, therefore

$$x^y - x^2 = 2-y$$

Because $x \ge 1$, we have $x^y \le x^2$ if $y<2$ and $x^y \ge x^2$ if $y>2$, i.e.,

- If $y<2$, $x^y - x^2$ **is non positive** but $2-y$ **is positive**.
- If $y>2$, $x^y - x^2$ **is non negative** but $2-y$ **is negative**.

Hence $y = 2$ is the only candidate for a solution.